# is it possible to create a view of data from a different google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I want to build a google sheet view , I thought since the data is already available in other google sheet for different purpose, would it be possible to pick up specific data from the sheet it exist to different google sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You mean sheets in single spreadsheet or different spreadsheet?

If sheets, then you can take a range using curly brackets

```
={sheet1!A1:C100}
```

If spreadsheets then you can use importrange formula

```
=importrange("url of the spreadsheet","sheet1!A1:C100")
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Where should I put importrange formula?

Comment: In the sheet where you want to have your data displayed. As formulas name suggest it takes a range from one spreadsheet and imports into another. Note - it does not import formulas or formatting.